# How to redefine type for React class prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-elements

I´m using [Avatar](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/avatar/) from [react-native-elements](https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements) and the ImageComponent prop is typed as React.ComponentClass (IntelliSense report type `React.ComponentClass<{}, any>`)

When using a functional component (with prop key) I get red squiggles under ImageComponent:

```
  <Avatar
    rounded
    size={c.styles.avatarSize}
    containerStyle={{ margin: c.styles.marginLRTB / 2 }}
    placeholderStyle={{ backgroundColor: colors.background }}
    ImageComponent={() => AvatarImage(key)}
  />
```

`Type '() => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<{}, any>'.ts(2769)`

AvatarImage:

```
  const AvatarImage = (key: string) => (
    <FastImage
      style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
      source={sourcesState[key].category === 'In-app' ? avatars[key as QuotesListKeys] : { uri: sourcesState[key].imageUrl }}
    />
  );
```

How can I fix this typescript error?

I´ve tried to define a new class/interface that extend Avatar/AvatarProps:

```
  type MyAvatarProps = Omit<AvatarProps, 'ImageComponent'> & { ImageComponent: FC<{ key: string }> };

  class MyAvatar extends Avatar<MyAvatarProps> {}
```

I get typescript error `Type 'Avatar' is not generic.ts(2315)`

How do I extend Avatar with MyAvatarProps when it's not generic?

Or is there other/better ways to handle this?

### Update:

See my answer below

Comment: If `AvatarImage(key)` returns `JSX.Element`, then try `ImageComponent={AvatarImage(key)}`

Comment: @RameshReddy I get a similar TS error: 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<{}, any>'.ts(2769). Also ImageComponent require the arrow function to work.

Comment: Based on this https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/avatar/#imagecomponent, the type can be an Element, so I'm not sure why it's only expecting a class component.

Comment: @RameshReddy Yes, that is true. I might create an issue reporting this. Anyway it would be nice to be able fix this with typescript as well.

Comment: Okay, before that ensure you're using the latest stable version and that you're not on an older version that doesn't support the functional component types.

Answer (score 1):

I got around the issue with a simple TS cast:

```
ImageComponent={((() => AvatarImage(key)) as unknown) as ComponentClass<{}, any>}
```